# Подключение css только на страницах моего плагина

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подключаю нужные для моего плагина стили так.

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function(){
        wp_enqueue_style('my_plugin', PLUGIN_URL . 'css/admin.css');
    });
```

Но так стили подключаются сразу для всей админки. Например если мы перейдем на страницу настроек wordpress, то на ней тоже подключится мой css файл.

Как подключить стили только на страницах моего плагина? Типа такого:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function(){

if(проверка что мы именно на страницах моего плагина){
        wp_enqueue_style('my_plugin', PLUGIN_URL . 'css/admin.css');
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Так примерно должна выглядеть функция:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function(){

    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $page = substr($path, 0, -1);

    if (($page == '/page1') || ($page == '/page2')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('my_plugin', PLUGIN_URL . 'css/admin.css');
    }

});
```